# TYPO3 Linkvalidator Extension with MASK

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to use the extension Link Validator to check links inside Mask Elements.

I checked the documentation but im too newbie for this..

Thanks!

Comment: according to this: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-linkvalidator/master/en-us/Configuration/Index.html
it should be sufficient to add to your page TSConfig:
mod.linkvalidator.searchFields.[nameoftable] = [nameofthefield].
I also found this page in german: https://www.itfoo.de/web/typo3-der-linkvalidator-und-eigene-extensions/

Comment: If you agree, I'll add the same comment as answer

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi just do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-linkvalidator/master/en-us/Configuration/Index.html) it should be sufficient to add to your page TSConfig:

```
mod.linkvalidator.searchFields.[nameoftable] = [nameofthefield]
```

I also found this page in german about this topic:

https://www.itfoo.de/web/typo3-der-linkvalidator-und-eigene-extensions/

with a more complete example:

```
mod.linkvalidator {
    searchFields {
        pages = media,url
        tt_content = bodytext,header_link,records
        tt_news = bodytext,links
        tx_meineext_domain_model_data = bodytext,teaser
        tabellenname = feldname,feldname    
    }
}
```